# type of those functions with type T in last argument position

Tags: typescript

I was hoping to create a type representing those functions with type `T` in the last argument position. Variadic tuple types looked like they would solve this without issue, but in my current approach, a type like:

`type TasLastArg<T> = (...args: [...any, T]) => any;`

has the `args` argument collapsed to `any[]`. There is similar behavior elsewhere that makes me think this *should* be possible; examples of what currently doesn't work / why I thought it would be possible:

```
type TasFirstArg<T> = (...args: [T, ...any]) => any;  // this appears to work as expected
type TasLastArg<T> = (...args: [...any, T]) => any; // would like for this to work

namespace T_in_first_place {
    const ok : TasFirstArg<string> = (x:string, y: number, z: string) => { return 0; }
    const correctly_fails : TasFirstArg<string> = (x:number, y: number, z: number) => { return 0; }
}
namespace T_in_last_place {
    const ok : TasLastArg<string> = (x:number, y: number, z: string) => { return 0; }
    const should_fail_but_does_not: TasLastArg<string> = (x:number, y: number, z: number) => { return 0; }
}

// there is some machinery that allows looking at the last type in a tuple:
type CheckStringIsLast<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer first, string] ? true : false;
type it_checks_this_fine = CheckStringIsLast<[number, number, string]>; // true
type it_properly_rejects_this = CheckStringIsLast<[number, number, number]>; // false
```

Is it not possible, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript 4.1 only supports rest elements at the *end* of tuple types.  Variadic tuple types allow you to *write* `[...any, T]`, but that just collapses to `any[]`.

When TypeScript 4.2 is released, it should start accepting rest elements at the beginning or middle instead (but just one rest element per tuple).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#41544](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41544) for the PR implementing this.  At that point, `[...any, T]` will be interpreted as `[...any[], T]`, meaning "any tuple with `T` at the end", as you intend.

Note that once this is supported, though, your example doesn't really do what you intend:

```
const ok : TasLastArg<string> = (x:number, y: number, z: string) => { return 0; } // error!
// -> ~~
// Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer
```

That is an error because while the target function does require a `string` as its last element, it does not conform to `TasLastArg<string>`, which needs to be a function that accepts *any* argument list that ends in a `string`.  Meaning you'd need to be able to call it this way:

```
ok("shouldWork");
ok(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, true, new Date(), "shouldAlsoWork");
```

which would be catastrophic for a function of type `(x: number, y: number, z: string) => number` if its implementation does anything meaningful with `x`, `y`, and `z`.  If you want to implement that it needs to be a function that is itself variadic in the right way:

```
const reallyOkay: TasLastArg<string> = (...args: [...initArgs: any[], lastArg: string]) => {
    console.log((args[args.length - 1] as string).toUpperCase());
}
reallyOkay("shouldWork"); // SHOULDWORK
reallyOkay(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, true, new Date(), "shouldAlsoWork"); // SHOULDALSOWORK
```

And no, it doesn't yet look like `args[args.length-1]` will be interpreted as `string` automatically, at least initially.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20210120#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwGIEsBODgEE0HMA8MAfFALxQAUAdDXHggFxQDaMANFDVXAHYgC6ASjIleIANxQoAemlRgACxQIocMJDorgAeygB3bWgDWqlRAAekAMbAIAEwBQoSLEQAZRNjyES5arXomZi4xDhghEVU+SVl9bQBXABs7KESUI2gAM0N5JS1dA2MHBx44AFsIBDA4K2gYAH0UHnrM9Ex6sESa6ABvBykpK20eTChtIyZ4ZDavAkw0JtxfSnMmecWOECYeeLKAIwg0DgAvNeAFnlxhUhIeqDQIYHi0HigABkkAX36BoZHgKBDNAPGyJEAtOAoRKMVzTDCzfDrS7LCirKA7faHTbbXYHI5QU7o3GHa63e6PZ6vD5Qb7fUoVKrdWCNZpddqdJl9AaA4ajcaTdyeHBzc6LFFojF47FEzH4wlIq6RO4PJ4vd5fGRyQ5oQwAQh+UliAFoSAA-U0GzWuPCPckAR3i6EqUAAzFAIIkIBUeMAKAhhHt4gCEAk0LUoGU4CAoAo4AA3LIQPSHS1-UYIBQJZIQqH1QPAep2bSVeo8bTAAUIDyYYWI0XIsgrHGy6WSrEE5t40lQZUUtXU76W8YUABEGazdgA6oYjCPBOIh0YKABGDgAJg4Lo4ABYOABWDgANg4AHYOOd4hAODwk1AACJwWwUQQcMeZpJ2LDQ7TT4xzhepryAIPHAiRggA8kYUaVtWCIKiiISBCwXBNCgswwmIzD8BwbKzGcFy4BENw9pa3JptonpUIk2i4BQFB0LgCDMAxCBURAlyKFARpQMu-CmFACqCFQOgAKrqIcADCiAQM+86Wt83IgWBICQVGo7jh+v6zvOVoAMoABLgSJbh3pO4EAEoANKWkpEFQSAK7rpuO77kep7nmgl7XreD5Pi+UBvhOX4hlp-56YZxl3lgbi6eBZlWcUg6xIohzQMoAnaBUEY1EoN5oNGiiPqoYHaHoKjUeMiyqACKWpJ48jgGlrxwPI8SdBADBOI1UASQoEBWEYUywYQ7rmLYPB2ComH8MsMCjeNk3ITQTSZIcUCtPCHAKnxAD88iedATCZKBCAQAuzhpQWVh9QNCD1IoygtE00DkL1-WDYKmD4Mwbb4r9W31oRRAxHIF4QF1LhoR0OqQGgYL1A8ABW-XAHdD0qK9N0fVWnjff9MpSgThwzSD60nRAQA)